# Xcode 11.5 Unable to open dependencies file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

I recently updated Xcode from version 11.3 to 11.5 and one of my packages (that I use in one of my app, I developed both the app and the package) can't compile because of a permission error:

```
error: unable to open dependencies file (/Users/arguiot/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Euclid_Calculator-esmjlsretjpuvpajvqzmllnvcpse/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Euler.build/Debug/Euler.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Fibonacci-PACKAGE:https://github.com/arguiot/Euler::MAINGROUP::REF_0::REF_32.d) (in target 'Euler' from project 'Euler')
Command CompileSwiftSources emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

It seems to be an Xcode problem (or `xcodebuild` toolchain) because the `swift build` command seems to work on the package. Unfortunately, there is no way of using the same command for my app, I have to use Xcode.

One obvious solution is to use Xcode 11.3 but WWDC and iOS 14 are coming and I don't want to be in a situation where I can't use the new features.

I already tried "common" stuff like cleaning the build folder, switching the build system to the legacy build system, ...

I also tried to give read & write access to everyone on the DerivedData folder (and subfolders).

Comment: It seems to be related to packages. I managed to get it to work by using `swift package generate-xcodeproj`

Comment: Actually, no... the project now compiles but when it's included in another project, it doesn't work anymore

Comment: This just happend to me too, with a struct named "AppConfiguration". Renaming the struct solved the issue magically. This is however not a real solution to this problem.